# elasticsearch exists filter for object type field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having trouble with a simple exist filter. What I am trying to achieve is , return all documents which have specific field.
following is he mapping for my index -

```
"book": {
"dynamic": "true",
"properties": {
    "currencies": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "properties": {
            "bookChallenge000": {
            "type": "long"
            },
            "achievements": {
            "type": "long"
            },
            "bookChallenge001": {
            "type": "long"
            },
            "giftsSent": {
            "type": "long"
            },
            "stars": {
            "type": "long"
            },
            "knightsDonated": {
            "type": "long"
            }
        }
    },
    "level": {
        "type": "long"
    },
    "description": {
        "index_analyzer": "str_index_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "additionalMaxMembers": {
    "type": "long"
    },
    "name": {
        "index_analyzer": "str_index_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "lastUpdated": {
        "type": "long"
    },
    "active": {
        "type": "boolean"
    },
    "bookClubId": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "attributes": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "properties": {
            "level": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "description": {
                "index_analyzer": "str_index_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "additionalMaxMembers": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "name": {
                "index_analyzer": "str_index_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "lastUpdated": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "active": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "memberCount": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "inviteStatus": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    "meta": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "properties": {
            "bookRewards": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "type": "object"
            },
            "challenges": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "type": "object"
            },
            "grantedRewardInfo": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "type": "object"
            },
            "levelRequirement": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "membersData": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "type": "object"
            },
            "language": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "conversations": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "type": "object"
            },
            "bookGoals": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "type": "object"
            },
            "banner": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    "memberCount": {
        "type": "long"
    },
    "inviteStatus": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "version": {
        "type": "long"
    }
}
}
```

here is a  document I am searching for -

```
{
attributes: {
    active: true,
    additionalMaxMembers: 0,
    description: "famous five",
    inviteStatus: "OPEN",
    lastUpdated: 1452119518547,
    level: 1,
    memberCount: 39,
    name: "zero"
},
currencies: {
    bookChallenge000: 74316,
    bookChallenge001: 142580,
    bookChallenge002: 165526,
    achievements: 582,
    giftsSent: 0,
    knightsDonated: 161,
    stars: 1104
},
meta: {
    banner: "enidBlyton_17",
    challenges: {
        Event014_Challenge_A: {
            Currency: "bookChallenge000",
            finishtime: 20550267,
            goalscore: 30240,
            memberscores: {
                37339561405: 10,
                37349022668: 2000,
                37432453846: 20,
                37437075798: 0
            },
            playerCurrency: "UserChallenge000"
        },
        Event014_Challenge_B: {
            Currency: "bookChallenge001",
            finishtime: 20290830,
            goalscore: 38003,
            memberscores: {
                37339561405: 20,
                37349022668: 38,
                37432453846: 590
            },
            playerCurrency: "UserChallenge000"
        }
    },
    language: "en_US",
    levelRequirement: 14,
    membersData: {
        37442021220: {
            achievements: 9,
            giftsSent: 0,
            knightsDonated: 0,
            playerLikes: 28,
            stars: 20
        },
        37493332413: {
            achievements: 4,
            giftsSent: 0,
            knightsDonated: 0,
            playerLikes: 0,
            stars: 20
        }
    }
},
active: true,
bookClubId: "6106890",
inviteStatus: "OPEN",
memberCount: 39,
additionalMaxMembers: 0,
lastUpdated: 1452119518547,
description: "famous five",
name: "zero",
level: 1
}
```

My query is pretty straight forward , I need all documents which have challenges field in them.

```
curl -X'GET' localhost:9200/book_index/_search -d '{"filter": {"exists" : { "field" : "challenges" }}}'
```

but it doesn't return any document, i have 100s of documents with challenge info.
I tried meta.challenges, and also challenges.membersData but it doesn't work.
though if I directly look for banner or language field, I get expected results, but not for object type fields.

How can I get all documents with challenges or membersData?

Please advise what am I missing.

Comment: Could you please provide at least one whole document? And a correct mapping because the one you have now looks broken.

Comment: sure, it was huge so cut parts of it, updated with full mapping and full document now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the query you are looking for:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "meta.challenges"
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "meta.membersData"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks awons, I tried this but zero results returned. is it because its object type?

Comment: Is it because its object type, because fi i query directly for the fields like levelRequirement , language or banner , i get perfect results (thought meta.banner doesn't work). with exists filter directly, as well as your query.  curl -X'POST' localhost:9200/books/_search -d '{ "query": { "filtered": { "filter": { "exists": { "field": "banner" } } } } }'

Comment: @nidhi I don't follow. The query works perfectly fine. https://www.found.no/play/gist/b51dc7a082344b4f24b1

Comment: Thanks Awons, yes there it does, I am doing something wrong, for me, meta.banner works, looking for field meta also works , but meta.membersData or meta.challenges doesn't work. btw thank you for the found.no playground, its very helpful.

Comment: @nidhi I updated the query to match your question better.